# Is there a quick way of only editing the frontend of a java web app?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, web-applications, frontend

So we have a spring web app running on a glassfish server, using angularjs in the frontend. 
My tasks are mainly to do with editing the frontend, so are there any quick methods of updating the frontend side of things rather than building and re-deploying every time I make a small edit to test changes?

Thanks

Comment: If you only have the source code of the app, tough luck, you'll have to build it. If it's a WAR you should be able to open it as a zip file, edit its content and repackage it. Don't compress the archive when you repackage it.

Comment: Keep in mind for future reference that this is one of the main reasons for avoiding the war/external-container style in modern projects.

Comment: How is it built and deployed *now*?

Comment: It's built with Maven, deployed onto glassfish application server. My quickest method now is to use cmd files every time I make a change, but this take some time when the only change I make is a small edit to the javascript